# How to describe function accepting multiple types of arrays using generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following typings declaration:

`public static Loop<Type>(arr:Type[], callback:(obj:Type) => void):void;`

This describes the signature for a function implemented with native JavaScript. It loops through each object in an array and passes it to the callback function, e.g.:

```
Loop(["hello", "world"], function(value)
{
    console.log(value);
});
```

I get working intellisense when used like in the example above, but I also want it working when the array can be of different types, e.g.:

```
let arr: string[] | number[] = [];
Loop(arr, function(value)
{
    console.log(value);
});
```

But the example above does not work - "value" is described with the 'any' type, rather than "string | number".

However, if the array is declared like `let arr: (string|number)[]`, it works as expected. But I'm not interested in having mixed arrays. It's either a string array or number array.

Can I declare the signature for Loop to work with e.g. `string[] | number[]` ?

-- Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

In this case I think you'll find it easier to make your `Loop` function generic in the array type, not the element type.  Like this:

```
  public static Loop<A extends readonly any[]>(arr: A, callback: (obj: A[number]) => void): void {
    arr.forEach(v => (callback(v)));
  }
```

Here, `A` is the array type, and `A[number]` is the element type (because if you have an array of type `A` and index into it with a key of type `number` you should get one of its elements).

Let's make sure it works:

```
let arr = Math.random() < 0.5 ? ["a", "b", "c"] : [1, 2, 3];
Loop(arr, function (value) {
  console.log(typeof value === "number" ? value + 1 : value.toUpperCase());
});
// A B C or 2 3 4
```

Yes, `arr` is accepted, and then `value` is contextually inferred to be the union `string | number`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oAcCuAjEAlsNBAC5ilHQAyimAPAILQCmAHqSwHYAmMATizA94XEAE9oYLuIDaAXQB8ACjD9+ALmiMANNGBgQIXGGABrLcvi4AVlsayu2ALa4W-eQEpoAXkXQAN3gCHk8tIJCUdAwpdQA6ADN4fgBRUwALZQDff2UDIxNzLM8SgG5ogF9UKtQQFlJY-l9oAFkKdLj+aRFnZW96aAAGOIBWaAB+aFkAIjBpvWnceehp4Gn5aC1ZAEY9ACY9AGZ5coR4ONp4TFV1PQTsLmBKUWgsw2wWbzQMYFEIeDqcRA8AA5spSOJMCx4AlAu8WL4fD4Vk5XO5phM4SAPtAANTQbabLEfOKkeAAVUwUP4AGFICw+p5yhUmagAPRs7TQABC0Bp0GS0D20EO0AALKh0EA)

Comment: Thanks jcalz.
I will give it a try and see whether I like yours or Linda's solution the best. I appreciate your input - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The issues with a type like `string[] | number[]` come up a lot and I have a go-to solution that I like to use.  This is a bit of a hack, but when we say that your type is `(string[] | number[])` ***and also*** `(string | number)[]`, then you no longer have issues calling functions like `array.map` or your `Loop` method.  The import part is that the array must fit **both** of those definitions, so it doesn't allow for mixed arrays.  You can put this into a utility type:

```
type ArrayOfEither<A, B> = (A[] | B[]) & (A | B)[]
```

You don't need to make any changes to your `Loop` method, but you *do* need to make a change to how you declare your variable `arr`.

```
let arr: ArrayOfEither<string, number> = [];
```

```
arr = ["1", 2, 3] // error: Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'ArrayOfEither<string, number>'.
arr = [1, 2, 3] // ok
```

```
Loop(arr, function(value) {
    console.log(value);  // value is `string | number`
});
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/vW4aaw)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give your suggestion a try, and see whether I like this approach or jcalz' approach better. Thank you - much appreciated :-)